# My Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't automatically lock

Tags: 15.10, lock-screen

The setting in brightness and lock seems to do nothing. I think this has bug has been around for a while does anyone know the solution? Or how I might be able to diagnose it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Brightness does not change due to unsupported hardware on laptops. In desktops hardware buttons exist. Searching display model for Linux support can provide more information